# iphone SIGABRT error with registerForSystemEvents unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, selector

Hi I keep try to debug my iPhone app in the iPhone simulator firmware 4.2, but none of the apps open up and I receive this error called "SIGABRT" and the gdb says:

`+[MyAppDelegate registerForSystemEvents]: unrecognized selector sent to class...`

I never called this function ever... all I did was "New Project" and then "Build and Run"

any suggestions as to how to fix this error?

Thanks,
Thommaye

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method called `registerForSystemEvents:` on your delegate class, and you don't have a class method in your delegate with that name. Showing the code will also help.

Comment: thing is i did not call that event ever. i just said "new project" and then build and run...

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this error for a while and couldn't figure it out till just now, so I wanted to throw in what worked for me, just in case someone else stumbles upon this.

In my scenario, I have a `PadController.h` and a `PhoneController.h` that both inherit from `AppController.h` and I kept getting the error that `AppController` couldn't `registerForSystemEvents:`

It was failing on a static call, so that it was essentially trying to do `[AppController registerForSystemEvents:]`

My `AppController` looked like this:

`@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

First:
Make sure your App Delegate inherits from `NSObject` and conforms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

Second:
I had in my plist a line that said Principle Class which was pointing to AppController. Getting rid of this is actually what worked for me specifically. I think it was trying to launch AppController twice (once from Interface Builder and once from this).

Third:
Make sure your `main.h` looks something like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

        return retVal;
    }
```